# Laravel add columns in the index in repo or entity or else

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have the following files and I want to make a index blade where the columns are feed by an object. What's the best place to store an array or object with `Id`, `Title`, `Description` and `Remove` so I can feed the `index.blade.php`

Files:

```
BannerController
Banner.php - entity
BannerModel.php
BannerRepository.php interface
EloquentBannerRepository.php
```

Index.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.cms')
@section('title', 'Banners')
@section('content')
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th><---This
            <th>Title</th><---This
            <th>Description</th><---This
            <th>Remove</th><---This
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        etc etc
```

Comment: Is there any reason why don't you want to have column titles in your view like now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to pass a collection of items to the view

```
public function index()
{
    $items = Item::all(); // it's just an example, get the collection of items however you want

    return view('view.name',compact('items'));
}
```

Then in the index.blade.php fiel you could do something like this:

```
@foreach($items as $index=>$item)
     <tr>
         <td>{{ $index+1 }}</td>
         <td>{{ $item->title}}</td>
         <td>{{ $item->description}}</td>
         <td>
           <a href="{{ route('items .edit',$item) }}"><i class="fa fa-pencil glyphicon-edit"></i></a>
           <a href="{{ route('items .destroy',$item) }}"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></a>
         </td>
     </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: The items in your example are defined in the controller?

Comment: Thats not what i want, sorry, i want to define constants in a specific class or interface. I want less code in my controllers. And then whats the beste

Comment: It will be a thin controller

Comment: You do a foreach through the td i want th, and not the value of the entity but heading columns